# pageBlockTable - row number variable is not incremented

Tags: visualforce, pdf, pageblocktable

I am creating PDF page (in html page not working too), I have pageBlockTable in it. I need to display row number in first column. I found solution to use `apex:variable` and increment it.

```
 <apex:variable value="{!0}" var="index"/>
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!salesOrderItems}" var="salesOrderItem" border="1px">
        <apex:variable var="index" value="{!index + 1}"/>
        <apex:column>
            <apex:facet name="header">
                <apex:outputLabel value="Number" />
            </apex:facet>
            <apex:outputLabel value="{!index}" />
        </apex:column>
        ...
     </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

But in every row I see 0. Increment is not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The dataTable and pageBlockTable elements do weird things for content *outside* of apex:column elements (usually by way of ignoring the content entirely). If you put the counter inside a column, it will work:

```
<apex:page controller="counter">
    <apex:variable value="{!0}" var="index" />
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!elements}" var="element">
            <apex:column>
                <apex:outputText>
                <apex:variable value="{!index + 1}" var="index" />
                {!index}
                </apex:outputText>
            </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Your solution to do it with css - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/111919/show-row-number-in-page-block-table works in html, but not in PDF

Comment: @VladyslavKushney Yeah, the CSS engine in PDF mode is a bit behind the times. I had thought there was a solution were you could increment a counter in a table, and there was actually another question recently about content appearing outside the table, which reminded me of that idiosyncrasy.

Answer (score 4):

According to [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_variable.htm) page, it is unsupported.

Though most of us have used it inside of an `<apex:repeat>` without problems, I suspect that the VF engine works differently in an `<apex:PageBlockTable>` and the counter does not get incremented.

Comment: Sorry... I figured out it was something else. The trick is simply to use CSS instead.

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/111919/show-row-number-in-page-block-table/111927#111927 as an example.

Comment: ... and I was wrong. Code sample incoming.